# LINQ query on sorting the data

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have an object View model which has Id field in the properties. My ID are in following form:

```
001_001
001_002
002_001
002_002
002_003
002_004
003_001
```

and so on... I want to sort the data but when I sort it sort thinking it string.
So, what I want is it should sort it as int. So, I have following linq query:

```
ObjectViewModels.OrderBy ( ids => ids.id )
                .GroupBy ( s => int.Parse (s.Id.ToString().Split (new string[] {"_"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1] ) ).ToList ( ) ;
```

But it does not seem to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want to sort based on the second value in your string ? If that is the case, why are you using `GroupBy` ?

Comment: I want to sort by both value. first it should be from first value and then second value. So, 001_001, 001_002 and all values of 001_sorted value and then 002_001, .. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` then re-sort using `ThenBy`.

I'm not sure why you do the `GroupBy` so I didn't add it to the example

```
ObjectViewModels.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.ID.ToString().Split('_')[0]))
                .ThenBy(y => int.Parse(y.ID.ToString().Split('_')[1]));
```